# Is DynamoDB DeleteItem secure?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

With DynamoDB I'm never sure what is happening on the other side. This makes me wondering: what exactly is happening once I fire a `DeleteItem` request?

I want to delete a record containing sensitive information once and for good, ideally so that it doesn't even stay in the underlying file system. Is it something DynamoDB can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the answer is no, given the distributed nature of DDB.

In fact, the [DDB Whitepaper](https://www.allthingsdistributed.com/files/amazon-dynamo-sosp2007.pdf) says

> Using this reconciliation mechanism, an “add to cart” operation is never
>   lost. However, deleted items can resurface.

But I also suspect it does not matter given the list of regulations DDB is compliant with...[Amazon Web Services: Risk and Compliance](https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/compliance/AWS_Risk_and_Compliance_Whitepaper_020315.pdf)

Even if DDB did "wipe" the sectors of disk where a given record was stored on a delete, the data would still be in your various backups.

I suspect the right answer is ti make sure you encrypt your DDB tables.